# Is it possible to implement method result caching based on field injection instead of a Map?

Tags: java, caching, aop, aspectj

I've seen some implementations of method result caching using AspectJ. For example, one in [jcabi-aspects](https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-aspects/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jcabi/aspects/aj/MethodCacher.java) or some [older examples](http://www.christianschenk.org/blog/caching-with-aspectj/).

The idea is that instead of writing bolierplate code for caching result of a method in a field, like this:

```
public Mesh someComplexGeometry() {
    if (this.geometry == null) {
        this.geometry = computeTheGeometry();
    }
    return this.geometry;
}
```

We annotate methods so AspectJ compiler changes their bytecode so that their result is stored somewhere after the first execution and retrieved on consecutive executions:

```
@Cacheable
public Mesh someComplextGeometry() {
  // just compute the mesh, very neat and clear
}
```

My concern here is that all the implementations of caching aspects I've seen are based on storing values in a `Map`. It also involves a quite complex process of constructing keys for those maps. I'm afraid that it could have some performance implications.

I think it would be ideal if there was an aspect that worked this way: for each of *n* methods of a class that are annotated with `@Cacheable`, add a field `private Object cache_n` to that class, then at the first method invocation store the result in a field, not in a `Map`, and then keep returning the field contents on consecutive method calls.

So the idea is to inject custom private fields for each annotated method during weaving instead of using a whole fat `Map`. But I can't figure out how to do that and if it is even possible.

The following aspect implements what I want, but only for the case when a class only has a single method annotated with `@Cached`:

```
public aspect Cacher {
    private Object cache;

    pointcut cached(): execution(@Cached * * (..));

    Object around(): cached() {
        if (cache == null) {
            cache = proceed();
        }
        return cache;
    }
}
```

Can I do that kind of caching with AspectJ? If I can't, are there any platform restrictions that disallow such a thing, or is it just not implemented in AspectJ language?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve such a field based memoization by using the `percflow` Per Clause. This will create an instance of your aspect for each method that is woven.

This of course should only be used if the method has no parameter. when a method uses parameter, you'll still need a map to know what result to return based on the parameter.